# Gulp copy flatten only one sub folder

Tags: gulp

I have directory structure

```
|__apps  
| |__app1  
|   |__dist
|      |__sub
|         |__**  
|      |__**  
| |__app2  
|   |__dist
|      |__**
```

My current code

```
gulp.task('move', function() {
  gulp.src('./apps/{app1,app2}/dist/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

But its make

```
|__dist
| |__app1
|   |__dist
|      |__sub
|         |__**  
|      |__**
| |__app2
|   |__dist
|      |__**
```

And I want to copy to this structure to (flatten dist folder when copy app1 and app2)

```
|__dist
| |__app1 
|    |__sub
|       |__**  
|    |__**
| |__app2
|    |__**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was with plugin gulp-rename

```
gulp.task('move', function() {
  gulp.src('./apps/{' + apps.join(',') + '}/dist/**/*')
    .pipe($.rename(function(path) {
      var parts = path.dirname.split('/');
      parts.splice(1, 1);

      path.dirname = parts.join('/');
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
 });
```